# Angular-Formly dynamically change select options

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-formly

I would like to know if I could change select options using [Angular-Formly](http://angular-formly.com/) depending on another select's selected value.

Lets say I have **beverageTypeSelect** and **drinkSelect**.

**beverageTypeSelect** has options *Alcoholic* and *Non-Alcoholic*.

- **drinkSelect** would have *Heineken*, *Budweiser*, *Alcohol 96%*, if **beverageTypeSelect** value is *Alcoholic*.
- **drinkSelect** would have *Coca-Cola*, *Pepsi*, *Water*, if **beverageTypeSelect** value is *Non-Alcoholic*.

How can I do that?

**Editing:**

Ok, let's try to make it a little more clear:
This is not my real application, but I want to keep it simple and get the general solution for this, so I'll keep with the beverage.

We are using https://github.com/formly-js/angular-formly-templates-bootstrap.

We have a formly forms generator. The part of code that is interesting in here is this:

```
if (obj.ngOptions){
    o.templateOptions.options=[];
    o.templateOptions.ngOptions = obj.ngOptions;
}
```

We have figured out that options must by an empty array so ngOptions can take place.

So we have a formly form like this:

```
[{
    key: 'beverageTypeSelect',
    type: 'select',
    templateOptions: {
        options: [{
            name: 'Alcoholic',
            value: 'A'
        }, 
        {
            name: 'Non-Alcoholic',
            value: 'N'
        }]
     }
}, {
    key: 'drinkSelect',
    type: 'select',
    templateOptions: {
        options: [],
        ngOptions: 'item as item.label for item in model.drinkSelect track by item.id'
 }]
```

Then we'll have a html to show our form:

```
<formly-form fields="formFields" model="DrinkingCtrl.data" form="DrinkingCtrl.form">
</formly-form>
```

And, finally, our controller:

```
'use strict'

angular.module('drunkApp')
  .controller('DrinkingCtrl', drinking);

function drinking($scope, $stateParams, $state, $reactive, AutoSaveReactiveFormScope) {
  var self = this;
  var vm = AutoSaveReactiveFormScope($scope, this, 'NAME_TO_SEARCH_FOR_DRINK_FORMLY_FORM', 'drinkPublishName', drinkMongoCollection, $stateParams.id); // This is a factory that gives us everything (or almost it) that we need in a controller with form autosave functionallity :).

  var drinkOptions = [{
    id: 'H',
    label: 'Heineken',
    types: ['A']
  }, {
    id: 'B',
    label: 'Budweiser',
    types: ['A']
  }, {
    id: 'A',
    label: 'Alcohol 96%',
    types: ['A']
  }, {
    id: 'C',
    label: 'Coca-Cola',
    types: ['N']
  }, {
    id: 'P',
    label: 'Pepsi',
    types: ['N']
  }, {
    id: 'W',
    label: 'Water',
    types: ['N']
  }];

  vm.autorun(function() {
    if (self.data) {
      self.data.drinkSelect = _.filter(drinkOptions, function(drk) {
        return _.contains(drk.types, self.data.beverageTypeSelect);
      });
    }
  });
}
```

This really works, but I was expecting something cleaner, something that I could do directly inside of the form declaration. Maybe do something like we can do with required or hideExpression (that we can write something like 'model.option1 != "BLA"' or a function).

p.s.: Hope this time I made myself clearer.

Comment: Please be more specific and `try it yourself first`. There are almost always a number of possibilities to tackle a problem in AngularJs. Try it first and come back if a have a **concrete** problem with your attempt of a solution. To be honest, as it currently stands it reads like you want us to do your work for you.

Comment: That's just rude. What makes you think you can say something like "Try it first and come back if a have a concrete problem"? I really can explain better what I want, but don't you go judging without knowing. If you don't want to help, just don't.

Comment: I didn't intend to be rude and I don't think I was. I think I can say this, because we as the SO community have given us this rules ourself and questions and answers have to follow certain restrictions here. Please read more at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask about how to ask a good question on SO. I invite you to do this because it also greatly increases the chances of your question being answered.